# to take screenshot of a div in html using php

Tags: php, gd

I am collecting all the profile pic of my friends . Then i am putting all the images in a div .I am working in a php language . So i want to take the screenshot of that div and make it downloaded as a jpeg or png . So if anybody can help me

Comment: Not possible using standard libraries (and any extensions I'm aware of). Generally, from PHP you can't run anything on user side. Use JavaScript for that.

Comment: Can't you at least do a quick Google? https://browshot.com/api/libraries/php

Answer (score 1):

Since the pictures reside in a div, which is in the client side, and php runs in the server side, **you can't use php to get the pictures**.

What you can do is send the pictures to the server (file upload) and manipulate it there.